# Word macro VBA: Fit the image to the shape

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to fit the image to the shape. The code is simple:

```
Function CmPt(cm As Single) As Single
' Convert centimeters to points.

    CmPt = Application.CentimetersToPoints(cm)
End Function

Sub InsertCanvas()
' Insert puzzle image canvas to the document.

    Dim edge As Single
    edge = CmPt(4)

    Dim canvas As Shape
    Set canvas = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, Left:=CmPt(2.5), Top:=CmPt(2.5), Width:=edge, Height:=edge, Anchor:=Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range)
    
    Dim image_path As String
    image_path = ActiveDocument.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "images" & Application.PathSeparator & "image.jpeg"

    With canvas
        .Line.Weight = 1
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(64, 64, 64)
    
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .Fill.UserPicture image_path
  End With
End Sub
```

But now, the image is filling the square. I would like to fit the image. I know that Word can do it, but I believe I have to compute itself from the original aspect ratio. Is possible to get original size of the `.UserPicture`? Or is possible to get the width and height of any picture on the hard drive without inserting the image into the document? Thank you

Comment: Do you only need the picture dimensions? The above code stretches the picture to the shape container dimensions. I can show you how to extract dimensions (in pixels)

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear but what I think you want is to add a picture to a shape and if the picture doesn't have the same aspect ratio have dark grey bands appear on the smaller sides. This isn't possible. A shape can either have a colour fill or an image fill, not both.

Comment: Timothy Rylatt it is possible. But it was not the question. The question was about original image size to calculate aspect ratio. @FaneDuru it is exactly what I want. How to get original dimensions of the image?

Comment: @Timothy Rylatt Oh, I am sorry, now I’ve realized what exactly you said. I don’t know if you are right, but it is possible to achieve the behaviour you described with some (maybe default) background. Maybe you are right it is not possible to set background color together with an image, but it is possible to change linked image dimensions to keep original aspect ratio.

Comment: Please edit your question and describe the UI functionality you are trying to replicate. The VBA object model doesn’t include all the functionality of the UI, so it may be that there isn’t a direct equivalent and you’ll need to think of a work around, e.g. putting the image into a single cell table of a fixed size.

Comment: I will see what @FaneDuru give me. If he is able to show me, how to extract dimensions of my image, it is exactly what am I looking for. And yes, the first idea of the solution of my whole macro was to use table with fixed size of cells. Maybe I will use it, but for now, I am looking for the way to get the dimensions of a picture from my hard drive.

Comment: Sorry, I was not able to see your comment. I can see an answer poste by you, too. I had in mind a very fast solution, not needing to import anything. Using "Shell.Application". Since you need only the ration between the two dimensions, returning in pixels does not matter. I will post such a function. It should be easy to implement it in your existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next function. It will extract the image dimensions without importing it in any way:

```
Function ImgDimensions(ByVal sFile As String) As Variant
    Dim oShell  As Object, oFolder As Object, oFile As Object, arr
    Dim sPath As String, sFilename As String, strDim As String
 
    sPath = Left(sFile, InStrRev(sFile, "\") - 1)
    sFilename = Right(sFile, Len(sFile) - InStrRev(sFile, "\"))
 
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set oFolder = oShell.Namespace(CStr(sPath))
    Set oFile = oFolder.ParseName(sFilename)
 
    strDim = oFile.ExtendedProperty("Dimensions")
    strDim = Mid(strDim, 2): strDim = Left(strDim, Len(strDim) - 1)
    arr = Split(strDim, " x ")
    ImgDimensions = Array(CLng(arr(0)), CLng(arr(1)))
End Function
```

It may replace your importing lines from the code above, and `picture` declaration:

```
   Set picture = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture(image_path, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
    width = picture.width
    height = picture.height
    picture.Delete
```

with:

```
   Dim arr
   arr = ImgDimensions(sFile)
   width = arr(0): height = arr(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found suitable solution for me. I know it is not ideal, and I can't say I like it, but it is enough and it is working correctly. I post only a snippet here:

```
Dim width As Long
Dim height As Long

Set picture = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture(image_path, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
width = picture.width
height = picture.height
picture.Delete
```

**Edit:**
The whole vba code for Word macro

```
Function CmPt(cm As Single) As Single
' Convert centimeters to points.

    CmPt = Application.CentimetersToPoints(cm)
End Function

Sub InsertPuzzleCard()
' Insert puzzle card to the document.

    Dim edge As Single
    edge = CmPt(4)

    Dim canvas As Shape
    Set canvas = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, Left:=CmPt(2.5), Top:=CmPt(2.5), width:=edge, height:=edge, Anchor:=Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range)
    
    Dim image_path As String
    image_path = ActiveDocument.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "images" & Application.PathSeparator & "image.jpeg"
                                                                               
    Dim picture As Shape
    Dim width As Long
    Dim height As Long
    Dim ratio As Single
    Dim new_width As Long
    Dim new_height As Long
    
    Set picture = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture(image_path, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
    width = picture.width
    height = picture.height
    picture.Delete
    
    ratio = width / height
    If ratio < 1 Then
        new_width = width * edge / height
        new_height = edge
    Else
        new_width = edge
        new_height = height * edge / width
    End If
    

    With canvas
        .Line.Weight = 1
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(64, 64, 64)
    
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.UserPicture image_path
        
        .PictureFormat.Crop.PictureWidth = new_width
        .PictureFormat.Crop.PictureHeight = new_height
  End With
End Sub
```